# jquery validation string contains exact substring

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

The text validation in jquery, String contains exact substring not partial.
Ex: Input String : **Hello World**  Sub String : **Hello** There are validation in like `str.indexof(SubString) >-1 or /SubString/.test(str)` If some one enters He in the input text box it validates the above condition where it should validate exact string "**Hello**" not for **He**. How to do this. Your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

/Hello/.test(Hello World) - correct validation as **Hello** World

/Hello/.test(He..) - It should n't validate, Where it validates for **He** llo in **He**..

```
 setValidation: function(){
 $.validator.addMethod("no_Hello_word", function(value) {
              return /hello/.test(value) || /HELLO/.test(value);
          }, "Text mustn't contain word hello/HELLO");
}
```

Comment: use word boundaries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.validator.addMethod("helloworld_word", function(value,element) {
              return /^((?!helloworld).)*$/i.test(value);
 }, "No Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

`return !/hello/i.test(value) || /Hello/.test(value)`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do it like this? This should not validate if the user puts in "he"

```
var string= "hello, world";
var string_array= string.toLowerCase().split(" ");

if (string_array.indexOf("hello") >= 0){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it neither check for exact word.instead hello if you put he and check indexof it will return same index i.e it just checks the index matched letter.

Answer (score 0):

what about this: split the string by spaces and then search in the array the word:

```
var exactSearch = function(word, string){
    var words = string.split(" ");

    for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        if(word == words[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

See the working example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y7e8f7L/)

**UPDATE**

I think I write the answer before you edit the question.

Maybe it works for you:

```
$.validator.addMethod("no_Hello_word", function(value, element) {
    return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "hello"));
},
    "Text mustn't contain word hello/HELLO!"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isValid(str){ 
    return !/[hH]ello/.test(str); 
}

// isValid('Hello') -> false
// isValid('Hello World') -> false
// isValid('He') -> true
```

You can flip this if you want the validation to be other way round.